# Locking 10 rows for processing and then deletion in spring jpa

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-data-jpa

I have a mysql table that is being appended to by two processes and two separate processes are reading from the table to process the records. The records once written are not updated.

Each of the reading processes wake up every hour to check if any records are present and to process the records. Once the processing is done the records need to be deleted so that the records are not processed again.

I am using spring JPA with mysql. For now I am thinking of using PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock to query & lock 10 records at a time and then delete them. Can I use Pageable to query the records while using PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock? And, will Pageable lock only one page of records?

I wanted thoughts on this approach and if others have tried this. I would appreciate any feedback.

Regards,
Ash

Comment: That depends on query, somethimes JPA fetch all data and then process and somethimes use limit offset for query. For 2nd case it okay to do it. Why don't you  try first ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using LIMIT to get 10 rows each time. In my SQL I also added "FOR UPDATE" to lock them. Then I processed the rows and deleted the 10 rows in the same transaction.